# Angular diferencia entre concatenar con 'coma' (,) o con 'el signo mas' (+)

Tags: javascript, angular

Hola me gustaria saber **cuando usar uno u otro ya que he visto que los resultados son diferente**

En estos **dos casos**  que imprimo un **array** de objetos:

- Caso 1:

  `console.log('Lista usuarios (dentro funcion http): ',this.lista_usuarios);`
- Caso 2:

`console.log('Lista usuarios (despues de  funcion http): ',this.lista_usuarios);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe concatenación con `,` en JavaScript (si lo intentas funcionará como un valor de retorno en algunos casos). La concatenación que conoces en `console.log`, funciona como una guía para mostrar y diferenciar los objetos según su tipo, sea número, cadena, objeto, array, función, etc. Si concatenas un objeto con '+', te imprimirá lo que es y no lo que contiene su valor.
Ej:

```
'Hola' + 'Mundo' //HolaMundo
'Hola' + {a:'Mundo'} //Hola[object Object]
'Hola', 'Mundo' //Mundo
'Hola' + Array //Holafunction Array() { [native code] }
//Correcto
console.log('Hola ', this.lista_usuarios, ' El total de usuarios es:', this.lista_usuarios.length)
//Forma inusual
console.log('Hola' + this.lista_usuarios + ' El total de usuarios es:' + this.lista_usuarios.length)
```

Comment: Ahh!!, de acuerdo, me quedo clarisimo. Mil gracias